# What does this mean...why is there a $ sign before the view. i.e @extends($master)

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the entire master file.

```
@extends($master)


@section('content')
    @include('ticketit::shared.header')

<div class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            @include('ticketit::shared.nav')
        </div>
    </div>
    @if(View::hasSection('ticketit_content'))
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline flex-wrap">
                @if(View::hasSection('page_title'))
                    <span>@yield('page_title')</span>
                @else
                    <span>@yield('page')</span>
                @endif

                @yield('ticketit_header')
            </h5>
            <div class="card-body @yield('ticketit_content_parent_class')">
                @yield('ticketit_content')
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    @yield('ticketit_extra_content')
</div>

@stop
```

Comment: Looks like it's a PHP variable (that probably contains the name of the layout).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be "Laravel Blade" guessing from the syntax, I am not very familiar with that but I would guess that `$master` is a variable containing a reference to the master file.

I would check the Laravel Blade documentation and/or you could try searching the (entire) project files for that to see where it's defined and to what. Checking the documentation you could see how to declare variables first for example. Also any "parent" languages like php which Laravel is built on top of.

Comment: This post didn't initially have any tags or references to any programming languages so a bit tricky to answer then :)

Comment: PHP,  programming languages or tags Laravel